# JSF CommandLink with get request

Tags: jsf, commandlink

Currently I have serious problems with my webapp, because it has strange behavior behind a web proxy ISA Server 2006. I found the problem was because I was using h:links to call some pages and ISA makes cache from that. I change the h:link to h:commandLink but the cache is the same. Doing debug of the request with firebug I find this:

```
POST currentPage
GET nextPage
```

The first is the page where i made click and the second one is the page I want to go. 1. I don't understand why there are 2 request? 2. I dont know why the command is sending a GET request?

Can anybody help me.... ????

Comment: The behavior you mention is very strange. It would be better if you add a [sscce](http://sscce.org) of the code that present the problem.

Comment: This is recognizeable as POST-Redirect-GET pattern. This suggests that the command link is just sending a redirect after performing the POST action. This can in JSF2 be done by among others `return nextPage?faces-redirect=true";` in action method. Are you absolutely positive that the JSF webapp isn't doing that anywhere?

Comment: Thanks for your answer!... I continued with my debug and I find that PrettyFaces uses the pattern POST-Redirect-GET as you said BalusC and I think that is the reason for multiple request. Now the problem is how to avoid the second request as GET and send a POST?